# same dynamic action for multiple buttons APEX 5.0

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a apex report page where there are multiple submit buttons for each region of charts display. Each submit button is supposed to have same dynamic actions- the dynamic action is supposed to run if user does not selects any data so an error message will pop up and this dynamic action I want to work for all the buttons, so instead of adding dynamic action which is common for every button , I want to define it somewhere in the code so that it can be called during click of any button.
How this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is assign the same CSS class to all the buttons you want your dynamic action to fire on. Let's say you assign a class `.mybutton` to all the buttons in your chart regions.

Second create your dynamic action.

Event: Click
Selection Type: jQuery Selector
jQuery Selector: `.mybutton`

Define the condition if you need to. Go on with Action etc.

So now your dynamic action will be fired whenever the user clicks on a button with the `.mybutton` class.

If you need to identify each button by ID when clicked and your action is Execute JavaScript Code, you can use `thisTriggeringElement.id`.

Comment: You could also use alternative jQuery selectors to suit the application e.g. ID if you have already given your buttons static IDs for another purpose.

Answer (score 0):

For the particular Dynamic Action, in **Condition** region, under **Condition Type** you can select **Request is contained within Expression 1** and give your request(button request) in **Expression 1**